# Spring Boot with Cassandra 3.x driver

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I use Spring boot `1.3.8.RELEASE`. To use cassandra 3.x driver i tried something like below;

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
                <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
                <artifactId>cassandra-driver-dse</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But i get error;

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.DataType.asJavaClass()Ljava/lang/Class;
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraSimpleTypeHolder.<clinit>(CassandraSimpleTypeHolder.java:62) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:?]
```

I tried this cause at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5835 , there is a post ;

> Adopting the Cassandra 3 changes in Spring Data Cassandra 1.5
>   (Ingalls) does not impose breaking changes for Spring Boot. **Tested
>   the upgrade with Boot 1.3.3 and 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT.**

Isn't it supposed to be like above?
Where i am wrong?

**NOTE:** I was trying this example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-cassandra

Comment: `…does not impose breaking changes for Spring Boot…` means that one can use Spring Data Ingalls (that translates to Spring Data Cassandra 1.5) with Spring Boot 1.4. Spring Data Ingalls is available as M1 release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

spring-data-cassandra-1.4.0.RELEASE depends on `<cassandra.version>2.1.11</cassandra.version>` and `<cassandra-driver-dse.version>2.1.7.1</cassandra-driver-dse.version>`see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/1.4.0.RELEASE/pom.xml.

If you want to use Cassandra 3.x you should upgrade to spring-boot 1.5.x to benifit from spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra:1.5.x that depends on `<cassandra.version>3.0.0</cassandra.version>` and `<cassandra-driver.version>3.0.3</cassandra-driver.version>`see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/1.5.0.M1/pom.xml

Remove Cassandra driver dependency from pom file. Spring boot will provide the right version

Comment: Used `1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` and looks like it is working. Any idea when there will be `1.5.0.RELEASE` ?

Comment: Spring-boot 1.5.0 is not yet released.